# Makefile complication error. Undefined reference C Programming

Tags: c, makefile

This is my Make file. I have main.c in which I call a function called  SLCreate to create the sorted linkedlist. I included sorted-list.h in my main.c but it still doesn't work

```
COMPILER = gcc
CCFLAGS = -ansi -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -lm

all: main

debug:
make DEBUG=TRUE


main: sorted-list.o main.o
$(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o main main.o
main.o: main.c sorted-list.h
$(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c main.c
sorted-list: sorted-list.o
$(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o sorted-list sorted-list.o
sorted-list.o: sorted-list.c sorted-list.h
$(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c sorted-list.c


ifeq ($(DEBUG), TRUE)
 CCFLAGS += -g
endif

clean:
rm -f main
rm -f *.o
rm -f sorted-list
rm -f *.o
```

The Error:

/main.c:38: undefined reference to `SLCreate'

Comment: Your `main` target depends on `sorted-list.o`, but it's missing from your compiler command for that target.

Comment: Do you have a `main(...)` function in `sorted-list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Undefined reference" almost always means you have failed to link a needed object. Your `main` rule should be this:

```
main: sorted-list.o main.o
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o main sorted-list.o main.o
```

Or more concisely, this:

```
main: sorted-list.o main.o
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just for my understanding, can you tell me what
this "o $@ $^" mean?

Comment: @user3100209: they are [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables); `$@` expands to the name of the target, `$^` expands to the list of prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `sorted-list.o` to your compiler command line for your `main` target:

```
main: sorted-list.o main.o
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o main main.o sorted-list.o
```